# diff-in-diff regression - parallel assumptions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference

I want to run a diff-in-diff regression for a pre-post rollout experiment. Assume for a moment that I have subjects impacted by the experiments.

To validate the trends, I AGGREGATE subjects to a daily basis, and I found a 'PERFECT' (assume this) parallel trends between my control and treatment on a daily basis.

Once I go down to run my diff-in-diff regression, Do I need to run it on:

1. A subject basis , i.e. each row is one subject
2. A daily basis, i.e. I aggregate the data to a daily basis (the time period where I validate the trend).
3. A subject/daily basis, i.e. each row is one day for each particular subject.